# Custom wordpress query not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in the "archive.php" file (from my current active theme):

```
list($f_categ_name) = explode('/', get_category_parents($cat));
            if ( $f_categ_name == "X_CATEG") {
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'category_name' => single_cat_title( '', false ),
                    'meta_key' => 'x_categ_type',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                );
                // get results
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );                 // The Loop
                ?>
                <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
```

I have 2 categories : A (with 15 posts) and B (with 7 posts) and they have the same parent category(let's say **X_CATEG**). So basically I run the same code but `$the_query->have_posts()` returns **true** for A category and **false** for B category. **WHY?**

Using ***$GLOBALS['wp_query']->request*** I was able to debug the executed query and both queries (for category A and B) returned all post IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `WP_Query` arguments, `category_name` will be category `slug` Not Category title.

`single_cat_title` functions will return the page title if a category or tag archive is queried. [see reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title)

So You should use category `slug` in WP_Query arguments instead of category `title`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem (with a little adjustments).